# How to notify an API user once a process has been finished?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, sidekiq

I have an API where users can create, what I call, orders.

I enqueue those orders and process them via **Sidekiq** gem. When the process is done, I currently send an email to the user. However, I am looking on how to notify him programatically.

So, sending the user a **POST request** to a particular endpoint, telling him that the order has been processed.

I am wondering which kind of security or other technical things I should take into account when doing this, or if there is any kind of gem that would help me on developing this.

Answer (score 2):

you can check [pub/sub pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern) to do this...

when `sidekiq` finish processing then you `publish` an event... and you register the browser to listen to this event... which is better than sending the user a POST request to a particular endpoint, telling him that the order has been processed.

there are many libraries out there that can help you implementing the pub/sub pattern check the following...

- [PubNub](http://www.pubnub.com/developers/)
- [Pusher](http://pusher.com/)
- [Bunny](https://github.com/ruby-amqp/bunny)
- [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/)
- [Redis](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/redis-pub-sub-how-does-it-work)

please note that you will have to use the rails app as the publisher and the front end as the subscriber ( you can check equivalent libs for JS )

and if you are interested in implementing the pub/sub within the same rails app... i've looked a lot and found that only those are the working solutions ( for app to publish and listen to his published events without getting locked in the process )

- [EventBus](https://github.com/kevinrutherford/event_bus)
- [Event_BG_Bus](https://github.com/artmees/event_bg_bus)
- [Wisper](https://github.com/krisleech/wisper)

[this is a post on how to use those gems to implement pub/sub pattern](http://artmees.github.io/blog/2014/04/02/on-rails-pub-slash-sub-pattern/)

Comment: Why would I want my browser to listen to this event? I just need to inform the User that the order has been finished. THe user is an API user, somebody who creates orders not via a browser. I was thinking on something like this: https://payments.amazon.com/help/Amazon-Flexible-Payments-Service/Managing-Orders-and-Transactions/Receiving-Instant-Notifications

Comment: ok... maybe using the term "browser" is wrong... you can use any "api consumer" to listen to the event... and about sending end point POST request, I really don't know how I could implement that